# XML Metatags with Fixed width format

Tags: xml, utf-8, xml-parsing, fixed-width

As part of Siebel integration with an external system, have a requirement with XML used with Fixed width format.
Requirement is to have a XML message in SOAP Format in UTF-8 format for header/Sender details & Auth details.
But the main request/response should be in fixed width format in SJIS Charset.

Wanted to check if it's technically feasible to map both Meta tags and Fixed width format in XML.

Also, another part of the requirement is to have the byte limit. Request/response to have a limit of 11k bytes. If it crosses that limit, send the response in multi page format. Is there any XML page response concept possible?

XML Snippet:

[XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8jVG.png)

Regards,
DKG

Comment: Your posting is too abstract. Can you include some XML snippet and the code of what you have so far... maybe also point out what works or not

Comment: Please find the sample XML Snippet: <header></Header>
<Body> 
<SenderID> ABC </SenderID>
<AppData> 40 field information in fixed width delimiter (SJIS) </AppData>
</Body>

Comment: In the above snippet, I want to understand if you can include the Fixed width data inside a single Meta Tag. Also if the fixed width characters limit crosses 10000 characters, need to post the rest of data in next page for which I don't have a sample format yet.

Comment: would be helpful if you edit your post to include those xml samples... easier to read

Comment: Have attached the image for the XML snippet in the main post. Please do let me know if you have any questions.